# Run apk in ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, apk

Can I run Apk on ubuntu 20.04? I have an apk I have to run it in 50 min. and I don't have my mobile right now. And I have to check and send this apk to a company in just 50 minutes.

Comment: use emulator like genymotion and install your app and use it

Comment: Check online https://appetize.io/upload

Comment: Thanks, Bro Proud tell me in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Superb Emulator is Genymotion:
https://www.genymotion.com/download/
That's a free emulator but remind that If you have its account and good ram, processor.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

No need to install any software.

You can check online from below link.

https://appetize.io/upload

Comment: I am Checking, But it taking time to load

Comment: I have just checked my small app and it's working fine.

Comment: All slots for this account are currently in use. Please wait until a slot becomes available. This is coming

Comment: Please wait few min, it will appear your app

Comment: when I click tap to play its load and then display tap to play screen and not going forward.

Comment: can you share me you apk which you are uploading